# relationships in ms access do not communicate?

Tags: database, forms, postgresql, ms-access-2010, relationship

i am building a movie database and i am having some issues with forms in MS Access.

my project in more detail:

1.[image: ER Diagram]

2.PostgreSQL code (create tables of ER diagram)

```
CREATE TABLE People ( 
    birth_date  DATE    NOT NULL,
    last_name   CHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
    name    CHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
    person_id   SERIAL,
PRIMARY KEY (person_id) );

CREATE TABLE Roles ( 
    role_id SERIAL,
    role_name   CHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (role_id) );

CREATE TABLE genre ( 
    genre_name  CHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
    genre_id    SERIAL,
PRIMARY KEY (genre_id) );

CREATE TABLE Movies ( 
    movie_id    SERIAL,
    title   CHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
    rating  REAL    NOT NULL,
    release_date    DATE    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (movie_id) );

CREATE TABLE film_people ( 
    role_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, person_id, role_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES Movies (movie_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES People (person_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES Roles (role_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE film_genre ( 
     movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
     genre_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, genre_id),
     FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES Movies (movie_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES genre (genre_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

3.Using pgAdmim4

4.ODBC driver to link with MS ACCESS 10

My job is to design forms in access for insert data to the database.Forms about genre,people,roles is easy.The problem that i am facing is when i want to create a form for example:

```
1) rating (attribute from movies)
2) title (attribute from movies)
3) release_date (attribute from movies)
4) genre_name (atrribute from genre) <---- problem is here
```

.**Access not importing relationships for SQL linked tables** [image: so i create relatioships in access]

but the "Enforce Referential Integrity" options are greyed out because that is a function of the database setup at the server, not in Access.

My purpose is to create a form which i am able to insert a movie and the genre of the movie and tables movies,film_gerne to update correctly.

Any idea ?

Comment: You're likely going to need a bit of VBA code in there somewhere. Your table design allows for a movie to be categorised into multiple genres, so if you want your Access form to handle this, you could set up a form (for the movie) and sub-form (for the genres), in which case your sub-form's BeforeInsert event will need to set the movie_id from the parent form. Or you could have no sub-form and instead use a multi-select list box to select the genres with a button which will loop through the selected items and add records to the public_film_genre table. Will you use bound or unbound forms?

Comment: unbound forms. Till now i have created forms for film_genre and film_people and i just insert the ids not the names. For now i am ok, but if i want a more "user-friendly",  VBA is the solution like you said.Thanks a lot @Skippy .